# Problem with responsive nav menu in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with a navigation responsive menu.
When I resize the page, I can see the hamburger menu and everything works fine.But I am trying to put a toggle or slidetoggle in react like in jquery.I created a toggle button but does not work correctly. Above is the code, I created a handleClick button for the hamburger menu and a state cond. className="mynav" in css file is display:none;. I want when the size of page is small and when I push the hamburger button to see the menu.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import './Navbar.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Navbar extends Component {

    state = {
        cond: false,

    }


    handleClick=()=>{
        this.setState({


           cond:!this.state.cond
        })
    }


  render() {


    return (


       <nav>
            <div className="mylogo">
                <div className="logo">
                    <a href="#home">logo</a>
                </div>

                <div id="mybtn" onClick={this.handleClick}>

                    <div className="bar1"></div>
                    <div className="bar2"></div>
                    <div className="bar3"></div>
                </div>



            </div>

            {this.state.cond ? <div className="mynav"  >
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to='/'>home</Link>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <Link to='/projects'>Projects</Link>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <Link to='/contact'>Contact</Link>
                    </li>



                </ul>

            </div> :false

            }

       </nav>

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you state declaration in a constructor, something like this:

```
export default class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            cond: false,
        };
    }
```

Then your onClick method will have access to the keyword 'this'. It wasn't able to access this.state without that.